# display the number of excluded days from holiday leave

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `leaves_table` which contains `id, holiday_start, holiday_end`. I have another `leaves_holiday` table which contains the `public holiday name` and it's `date`. now i want to in the `leaves_table` to add a new column and exclude the days where it is a public holiday

lets say for example

**leaves_table**

```
id.  holiday_start.  holiday_end 
 1.    09-Jul-2022.   13-Jul-2022
```

**public holiday table**

```
holiday_name.  holiday_date
 christmas      10-Jul-2022
```

the query should return no of days excluded as 1

```
id. holiday_start.  holiday_end.   excluded days
 1    09-Jul-2022.   13-Jul-2022.        1
```

how do i do this?

here is the create table and insert

```
create table XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES
(
exclude_id number not null primary key,
holiday_start date not null,
holiday_end date not null
);

create sequence seq_exclude_id MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 2;

create or replace trigger trg_exclude_id
before insert 
on XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES
for each row
begin
:new.exclude_id:=seq_exclude_id.nextval;
end;

INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('23-Jul-2022','20-Aug-2022');
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('01-Jul-2022','02-Aug-2022');
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('13-Jul-2022','29-Aug-2022');
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('12-Jul-2022','01-Aug-2022');
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('01-Jul-2022','29-Aug-2022');
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('08-Jul-2022','08-Aug-2022');
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_EXCLUDES (HOLIDAY_START, HOLIDAY_END) VALUES ('03-Jul-2022','20-Aug-2022');


2nd table (public holiday calendar table)

CREATE TABLE  "XX_LEAVES_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS" 
   (    "PUBLIC_HOLIDAY_UAE_YEAR_2022" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    "HOLIDAY_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
   )
INSERT INTO XX_LEAVES_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS (PUBLIC_HOLIDAY_UAE_YEAR_2022, HOLIDAY_DATE) VALUES (National Day,'10-Jul-2022');
```

Comment: So, how did you started? Show us how far have you reached and where is the problem in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compare leave date rage with hodiday and get count as excluded_days

```
select l.id, l.holiday_start, l.holiday_end,
(select Count(1) from leaves_holiday lh 
where l.holiday_start<= lh.holiday_date and l.holiday_end >= lh.holiday_date) as excluded_days
from leaves_table l
```

Comment: works but returns everything as 0 which is wrong

Comment: have you use date datatype for dates? @lilpupper

Comment: yeah i did.....

Comment: check, i have modified condition @lilpupper

Comment: works now perfect, what did you do?

 but select l.id should be l.exclude_id

Comment: what if i want to also add a new column which shows the holiday name which has been excluded

Comment: need to add join than count for leave holiday@lilpupper

Comment: and how will you show in new column if excluded day is more than one @lilpupper

Comment: if you find this helpful than vote my answer @lilpupper

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create calendar of all holiday dates (`leaves_calendar` CTE in my example) and then join it to `public_holiday` so that you'd know which dates to exclude.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  leaves_table (id, holiday_start, holiday_end) as
  3    (select 1, date '2022-07-09', date '2022-07-13' from dual union all
  4     select 2, date '2022-05-25', date '2022-05-30' from dual
  5    ),
  6  public_holiday (holiday_name, holiday_date) as
  7    (select 'Christmas' , date '2022-07-10' from dual union all
  8     select 'My holiday', date '2022-07-12' from dual),
  9  --
```

Query begins here; first create a calendar ...

```
 10  leaves_calendar as
 11    (select l.id, l.holiday_start + column_value - 1 as datum
 12     from leaves_table l cross join
 13       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                           connect by level <= l.holiday_end - l.holiday_start + 1
 15                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16    )
```

... then return the result: start and end date, number of excluded dates and holiday names (you didn't ask for that, but ... not a problem)

```
 17  select c.id,
 18         min(c.datum) as holiday_start,
 19         max(c.datum) as holiday_end,
 20         sum(case when p.holiday_date = c.datum then 1 else 0 end) as excluded_days,
 21         listagg(p.holiday_name, ', ') within group (order by p.holiday_date) as excluded
 22  from leaves_calendar c left join public_holiday p on p.holiday_date = c.datum
 23  group by c.id;
    
        ID HOLIDAY_START   HOLIDAY_END     EXCLUDED_DAYS EXCLUDED
---------- --------------- --------------- ------------- ------------------------------
         1 09.07.2022      13.07.2022                  2 Christmas, My holiday
         2 25.05.2022      30.05.2022                  0

SQL>
```

---

With sample data you provided:

```
SQL> select * from xx_leaves_excludes;

EXCLUDE_ID HOLIDAY_START   HOLIDAY_END
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 23.07.2022      20.08.2022
         2 01.07.2022      02.08.2022
         3 13.07.2022      29.08.2022
         4 12.07.2022      01.08.2022
         5 01.07.2022      29.08.2022
         6 08.07.2022      08.08.2022
         7 03.07.2022      20.08.2022

7 rows selected.

SQL> select * from public_holiday;

HOLIDAY_NAME    HOLIDAY_DATE
--------------- ---------------
Christmas       10.07.2022
My holiday      12.07.2022
```

Query looks like this:

```
SQL> with
  2  leaves_calendar as
  3    (select l.exclude_id, l.holiday_start + column_value - 1 as datum
  4     from xx_leaves_excludesl cross join
  5       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  6                           connect by level <= l.holiday_end - l.holiday_start + 1
  7                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  8    )
  9  select c.exclude_id,
 10         min(c.datum) as holiday_start,
 11         max(c.datum) as holiday_end,
 12         sum(case when p.holiday_date = c.datum then 1 else 0 end) as excluded_days,
 13         listagg(p.holiday_name, ', ') within group (order by p.holiday_date) as excluded
 14  from leaves_calendar c left join public_holiday p on p.holiday_date = c.datum
 15  group by c.exclude_id;

EXCLUDE_ID HOLIDAY_START   HOLIDAY_END     EXCLUDED_DAYS EXCLUDED
---------- --------------- --------------- ------------- ----------------------------------------
         1 23.07.2022      20.08.2022                  0
         2 01.07.2022      02.08.2022                  2 Christmas, My holiday
         3 13.07.2022      29.08.2022                  0
         4 12.07.2022      01.08.2022                  1 My holiday
         5 01.07.2022      29.08.2022                  2 Christmas, My holiday
         6 08.07.2022      08.08.2022                  2 Christmas, My holiday
         7 03.07.2022      20.08.2022                  2 Christmas, My holiday

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: i already have both tables the xx_leaves_excludes table which contains data about the exclude_id, holiday_start holiday_end and a calendar given the public holiday name and its date. i just need the query to compare both tables and exclude any public holiday from the leaves table.

Comment: I presume you do have these tables. I don't, so - as you didn't provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, I used CTEs which *represent* tables you have. Just in case you didn't notice, I indicated where query you might be interested in begins - it is at line #10. Just precede it with the WITH keyword, i.e. `with leaves_calendar as ...`

Comment: yeah i got the query however im getting some errors. until i figure it out how can i provide you with both tables?

Comment: I don't know what you did nor which errors you got (as you didn't post them). Thank you for sample data; I edited the answer and posted what I already did, but now with "static" tables (not CTEs). Have a look, please.

Comment: yeah thank you. i got it now and understood what you did but i am getting an error of table does not exist, i double checked the query i think i may have missed placed somewhere in the query my holiday table name. 
i will edit and add my second table which is the holiday calendar table